# Helpers are our "Custom Server Controls"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it my understanding that Helper methods are really the place where you can do the hard core logic that we would have done in lets say custom controls in ASP.NET?  For instance I work for a .com which uses classic ASP.NET.  The nature of our site is VERY complex, so we reuse and render different forms for thousands of products.  Every product could have a different configuration form.  We have a very complext RenderForm.cs custom server control that performs all the logic.  Based on some configuration settings from a table in the DB, it says ok, for Product 1123 it reads the setup (that our users confugure form our internal admin system) and takes that and spits out the dynamic form (using literal controls and what not) to the p age.

So I'm thinking MVC now.  Yea yea, it's all done in the View.  Well partially.  You're still going to have a need to have some custom logic in some .cs where it's not all embeded in your view.  That would be foolish to think you're not going to have some class that will spit out some HTML..like some very hard core extensive helper methods.

So my question is, are helper methods or class where you now do your custom server control type  of logic?  it's basically kind of the same concept in that you need a place to put your "hard core" HTML rendering logic in some class other than a controller.  Your controller is not responsible for rendering.  So helper methods I guess are the so-called custom server controls in a way that I have in classic ASP.NET, figuratively speaking.  I just need a yes or now on is the consensus that helper methods is the place to do all my hard core reusable logic that spits out html to the page and where I can embed custom controls into my view?  Looks like it.

"Helpers are essentially static classes, designed to contain the UI logic that otherwise clutters up your UI. Think of these as UI utilities."  [link text](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/aspnet-mvc-preview-using-the-mvc-ui-helpers/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is right on. If you do it right, you will start with the HTML helpers that MVC gives you, and you will gradually build up your own set of helpers that do even more and more for your specific project. You can get to the point where your view has only a few lines of code, which say something like, "Render entire view for Product 1123". The helpers will become your own "language" of renderers specific to your project, and you will be applying configuration, validation and everything else in a very DRY (Don-t Repeat Yourself) manner. It's phenomenal.

*Update*: Of course, only presentation stuff should go in your helpers. The goal is to stay DRY in your views. You still need to be careful to put into your ViewModels the things that belong in the ViewModels.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "no"... or rather "only where you have to".  More often than not, you can instead do the logic in the Controller (or a Service) and end up passing all the data required back to the View in ViewData. Somtimes this will mean multiple Views from one ControllerAction, less often it will mean logic in your View, and occasionally it means HtmlHelpers.

When you decide to use Helpers, it should be with the consideration that this means generated markup that won't be... well, in your markup. If you have (or later hire) a designer, that can be a problem. Or if you need to make a minor change to your layout, where do you go first? Your View or your Helpers?

[Edit] Also should ask yourself this: where is my code more easily unit tested? In a Service class which is just handing back View Data, or in a class that builds entire chunks of HTML and returns them as a String? If you're using TagBuilder, as you probably should be, then any change in the implementation of TagBuilder (even a change of whitespace handling) will break tests on a Helper without your code changing.

I'm not saying "don't use Helpers", I'm saying "don't abuse Helpers".